# Postgres Creating Schema in a specific database

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I got one suggestion form stackoverflow.com to create schema in a specific database as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo; 
 \connect foo; 
CREATE SCHEMA yourschema;
```

But I am getting error as follows:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\" LINE 2:  \connect foo; 
>            ^
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Situation :

Login as postgress
create user u1
create database db1 with owner u1
\connect u1
create schema s1

Please help me in creating schema in a specific db.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the database? Are you doing this with the `psql` command line tool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works, if - *and only if* - you're using psql:

```
postgres@berry-pc:~$ psql template1
psql (8.4.10)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# CREATE DATABASE foo;
CREATE DATABASE
template1=# \connect foo;
psql (8.4.10)
You are now connected to database "foo".
foo=# \connect template1
psql (8.4.10)
You are now connected to database "template1".
template1=# DROP DATABASE foo;
DROP DATABASE
template1=# \q
```

`\connect` is a psql command. It's not normal SQL, so you can't use that in a .sql file. There is no way to do it from within a sql file, as far as I know. The rationale behind this, is that you should reconnect to a different database once you want to use that different database. This is for database separation. The reason MySQL has implemented the `use $database` syntax is because of it's lack of schema's, but PostgreSQL doesn't have a command like that, as a database should be separated in schema's, rather than databases.