# PostgreSQL: Create schema in specific database [NOT psql]

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Im trying to create a SQL file to import my database/schema/tables with PHP.

If I use the PgAdmin, it inserts a meta-command \connect after the CREATE TABLE
and this generates an error if I run the SQL with pg_query in PHP.

After read the following questions:
[PostgreSQL: Create schema in specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508267/postgresql-create-schema-in-specific-database)
and
[Postgres Creating Schema in a specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949401/postgres-creating-schema-in-a-specific-database)

I ask:
How I can create a new schema, inside specific database, with SQL commands (NOT psql commands)?
The specific database is not the default named 'postgres' database, but another created by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is if you are connected to another database you can't with pure SQL.

Due to the fact that there is no `use database;` in Postgres like in MySQL you have to open a connection to the specific database you want to create the schema in (e.g. with pg_connect in PHP).

The schema itself can be created with the `CREATE SCHEMA...` [sql command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createschema.html) as you might know.

Perhaps working with [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) is an option for you. I would also have a look at the sources of [phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php).

I hope that helped a bit.

*Jost

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ill try to do this by another way. Maybe, creating the table first, and after connecting with pg_connect to then run the script to create the schema and tables.